# react-native xcode 10.1 "config.h" file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Recently, I upgraded from Xcode 9 to Xcode 10.1 for my existing react-native project. My RN project worked perfectly from Xcode 9, but after opening it in Xcode 10.1, I cant build my project in Xcode 10.1. It gives error saying
cant find "config.h".

I have also tried cleaning and restarting the xcode.

Comment: Have you tried the following? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21274

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat obtuse quirk in 10.1 is that it switches legacy build settings to their new default. Go to your target's Workspace (or Project) Settings (File > Workspace Settings) and change `Build System` from `New Build System` back to `Legacy Build System`.

[image]